# Axis loading modules - Creating tempfile and failing

Tags: java, module, weblogic, apache-axis, axis

We are using axis for webservice communication between different system in house. Every once in a while the axis calls fail with a:

```
[org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils] - Created temporary file : C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\_axis2\axis248890addressing-1.41.mar
[org.apache.axis2.util.Loader] - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler
[org.apache.axis2.util.Loader] - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler
[org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] - org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(invalidmodule)
[org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] - The addressing-1.41.mar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler
```

Maybe one in 100 fails like that.

The code is deployed on a 50thread weblogic app server running the axis2 version 1.4.1.

As far as I can tell from the log, the "Creating tempfile" happens in every call(and it mentions the same file everytime), so my guess is that maybe a multiple thread access to the same file, but I dont know what to do about it.

Has anybody got some insights that could help us eliminate this?

**Update:**

I Found a similar issue on the mailinglist without answer: http://marc.info/?l=axis-user&m=124411691013763&w=2
and posted this question there as well: http://marc.info/?l=axis-user&m=124912603230939&w=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this issue
http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3204

and the

configContext.terminate()
was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @svrist

The link to the [JIRA page] http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3204 you provided informed me that an upgrade **to at least Axis2 1.5** was required to avoid this problem.

FYI, if are seeing any of these errors that were described in the question, you run the risk of a **hung thread** in your application. I had a hard time trying to track this down, so if you are seeing this stack trace, consider the upgrade:

```
"pool-2-thread-10" prio=10 tid=0xad5ab000 nid=0x35f8 runnable [0xa7d0b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:557)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:506)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:161)
    at ***org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:132) <- Infinite loop***
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:411)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:602)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:581)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:641)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    - locked <0xb4de1d10> (a org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:150)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:143)
```

............................The Rest Omitted...................................